# Memory leak in TensorFlow upon starting new epoch

Tags: python, memory, tensorflow

I'm working on a training script in TensorFlow to classify two different types of images. Here is the class that creates a data set object, which is used to generate batches and increment epochs. It works fine until the first epoch is completed. It then fails at the line `self._images = self._images[perm]` within the `next_batch` method. This doesn't make sense to me, since Python shouldn't be duplicating self._images--only reshuffling the data.

```
class DataSet(object):
  def __init__(self, images, labels, norm=True):
    assert images.shape[0] == labels.shape[0], (
      "images.shape: %s labels.shape: %s" % (images.shape,
                                         labels.shape))
    self._num_examples = images.shape[0]
    self._images = images
    self._labels = labels
    self._epochs_completed = 0
    self._index_in_epoch = 0
    self._norm = norm
    # Shuffle the data right away
    perm = np.arange(self._num_examples)
    np.random.shuffle(perm)
    self._images = self._images[perm]
    self._labels = self._labels[perm]
  @property
  def images(self):
    return self._images
  @property
  def labels(self):
    return self._labels
  @property
  def num_examples(self):
    return self._num_examples
  @property
  def epochs_completed(self):
    return self._epochs_completed
  def next_batch(self, batch_size):
    """Return the next `batch_size` examples from this data set."""
    start = self._index_in_epoch
    self._index_in_epoch += batch_size
    if self._index_in_epoch > self._num_examples:
      # Finished epoch
      self._epochs_completed += 1
      print("Completed epoch %d.\n"%self._epochs_completed)
      # Shuffle the data
      perm = np.arange(self._num_examples)
      np.random.shuffle(perm)
      self._images = self._images[perm] # this is where OOM happens
      self._labels = self._labels[perm]
      # Start next epoch
```

Memory usage does not increase during ordinary training cycles. Here is the portion of training code. `data_train_norm` is a `DataSet` object.

```
batch_size = 300
csv_plot = open("csvs/train_plot.csv","a")
for i in range(3000):
    batch = data_train_norm.next_batch(batch_size)
    if i%50 == 0:
            tce = cross_entropy.eval(feed_dict={x:batch[0],y_:batch[1],keep_prob:1.0},session=sess)
            print("\nstep %d, train ce %g"%(i,tce))
            print datetime.datetime.now()
            csv_plot.write("%d, %g\n"%(i,tce))

    train_step.run(feed_dict={x:batch[0],y_:batch[1],keep_prob:0.8},session=sess)

version = 1
saver.save(sess,'nets/cnn0nu_batch_gpu_roi_v%02d'%version)
csv_plot.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be because of this piece of code where you add a new `next_batch` operation to the graph

```
for i in range(3000):
    batch = data_train_norm.next_batch(batch_size)
```

The method `data_train_norm.next_batch` create a new TensorFlow operation, so you should call it only once and use the operation created (hold in `batch`). Have a look to the examples in the [doc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/docs_src/programmers_guide/datasets.md), e.g.:

```
dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.range(100)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

for i in range(100):
  value = sess.run(next_element)
  assert i == value
```

Also, when debugging TensorFlow memory leak, you can use `sess.graph.finalize()`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using : `dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size)`?

Try reducing the `buffer_size`. This worked for me